# Check quality of random numbers

Tags: .net, algorithm, random

I wrote a code which generates random numbers based on a private cryptography project ( for educational purposes ). Now i want to check how the quality of my random number generator is.

Tests i already did:

- Count all numbers together and check the distance to zero ( Numbers can be negative and positive )
- Compare the random numbers with the `System.Random` class ( The duplicated numbers are at the half of the .NET's random generator )

What can i further do to check how good the algorithm is working?

Comment: http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php

Comment: Note that there are two issues with testing RNGs and cryto: 1) Even insecure generators can pass any statistical test, including dieharder. 2) Even a secure PRNG algorithm can be insecure if it's insufficiently seeded. This is very hard to test for.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "The duplicated numbers are at the half of the .NET's random generator"? I'd like to see the test code for that. I don't think `System.Random` is that broken.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I used a `HashSet` to check if the data is unique and run the generation 22 million times. However the algorithm is not optimized yet and isn't really fast but it is used for terrain/level generation and speed doesn't matter there. I think i could even improve it to get event better results but i don't have so much time to do this. I don't think .NET's random is bad, but you can archive better results if you don't care about execution time.

Comment: I don't see much point in testing the Random class.  It certainly don't promise much.  If you want cryptographic quality random numbers then use the class that provides them, RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister). It's got a few years on its back but it's a darn good algorithm for generating pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It just passed the test with good results. Thank you!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Thanks for the link but i want to test my own RNG but there are some interesting links available.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. Just remember that when you test the numbers, you'll need to test them versus a certain **distribution**. My guess is that you'll be aiming for a *uniform* one but that can differ. Chi-square test is a common one but depending on the actual distribution of the randomness, there are others. Also, you might want to check if the randomness sustains in higher dimensions. (Heavy stuff - I did that as my diploma work some years ago.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can i further do to check how good the algorithm is working?

The ultimate way would be to give a formal proof for that it is *hard* to distinguish this pseudorandom sequence from a truly random sequence, e.g., by reducing this distinguishing problem to another problem that is proven (or at least strongly believed) to be hard (like for example taking the discrete logarithm).

This part of Cryptography is called *Provable Security*, which provides some nice proof techniques and concepts (hard-core predicates, one-way functions, distinguishing attack, hybrid distributions, ...). However, it can only be applied if your algorithm has a mathematical fundament that can be handled formally.

From this field, the very first quality check is: Would it be ok if you would tell the rest of the world all the details of your algorithm and all its concepts and ideas? If not, then there is something wrong, since no encryption scheme should base on hiding how it works. The *only* secret must be the individual secret key (resp. random seed), but not the algorithm itself. For example, the Caesar chipher is easy to break once it is known how it works. In contrast to that, AES is an open standard, but it is still believed to be secure.

Comment: The mathematical prove seems as the best solution to check the quality of the numbers but this seems very time consuming because i have to invest more time ( Which i actually not have available ).

Answer (score 3):

[TestU01](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/testu01/tu01.html) is a software library, implemented in the ANSI C language, and offering a collection of utilities for the empirical statistical testing of uniform random number generators.

See: P. L'Ecuyer and R. Simard, TestU01: A C Library for Empirical Testing of Random Number Generators ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, Vol. 33, article 22, 2007.

Answer (score 3):

Chi Square test is the standard statistical test for randomness quality.  See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Pseudorandom_Numbers/Chi-Square_Test for an implementation.

If you need to prove that it's **cryptographically** strong as well...well, that's a much harder problem.

Comment: This test fails if i use the .NET random number generator.